# Query to get employee of different departments

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables: `Employee`, `Department` and `employeeProject`.

The relation between `employee` and `employeeproject` is one-to-many. The relation between `employee` and `department` is many-to-one.

I want to write a query to select 10 employees who have worked in projects 3 and 4. The query should return employees of different departments if possible.

The query below kind of works. The only problem is that the relationship between `employee` and `employeeproject` is one-to-many, so it might return the same employee number multiple times.

I cannot use `distinct` because all fields in the `order by` clause should be used in `select` when using `distinct`.

```
select top 10 empid from employee e 
inner join department d on d.depId=e.depid
inner join employeeProject p on p.empid=e.empid
where p.projectID in (3,4)
order by row_number() over(partition by e.depId order by e.empid)
```

Comment: sample data and expected result will helps in answering the question in this portal

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a guess, but use an `EXISTS`?

```
SELECT TOP 10 e.empid
FROM employee e
     JOIN department d ON e.depid = d.depid
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM employeeproject p
              WHERE p.emdid = e.empid
                AND p.projectid IN (3,4))
ORDER BY e.depid, e.empid;
```

Comment: but if you order by depid it will give employees of same department in top 10.

Comment: Then change the `ORDER BY` to what you had @sandeepjohnson , this was, after all, a stab in the dark due to a lack of information.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest aggregating by employee, and then using an assertion the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT TOP 10 e.empid
FROM employee e 
INNER JOIN department d
    ON d.depId = e.depid
INNER JOIN employeeProject p
    ON p.empid = e.empid
WHERE
    p.projectID IN (3,4)
GROUP BY
    e.empid
HAVING
    MIN(p.projectID) <> MAX(p.projectID);
```

If the minimum and maximum `projectID` are *not* equal for a given employee, after restricting to only projects 3 and 4, then it implies that this employee meets the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `select distinct`?

```
select distinct top 10 empid
from employee e inner join
     employeeProject p
     on p.empid = e.empid
where p.projectID in (3, 4)
order by row_number() over (partition by e.depId order by e.empid);
```

Note that the department table is not needed.

Alternatively,

```
select top (10) e.*
from employee e
where exists (select 1
              from employeeprojects ep
              where p.emdid = e.empid and
                    p.projectid in (3, 4)
             )
order by row_number() over (partition by e.depid order by newid());
```